# React can't read array in array?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render this array inside of my array. Here is my data file

```
      export const SidebarData = [
        {
          title: 'Home',
          path: '/',
          icon: <AiIcons.AiFillHome />,
          cName: 'nav-text'
        },
        {
          title: 'Reports',
          path: '/reports',
          icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper />,
          cName: 'nav-text',
          subNav: [
            {
              title: 'Sub Reports',
              path: '/reports/subreports',
              cName2: 'subnav'
            },
            {
              title: 'Sub Reports 2',
              path: '/reports/subreports2',
              cName2: 'subnav'
            }
          ]
        }
 ]
```

Here is my code to display the data

```
    {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li onClick={showSubnav} key={index} className={item.cName}>

             // Tried to render array in array, but says cannot read map of undefined

              <div className='subnav-menu'>
                {SidebarData.subNav.map((subItem, index) => {
                  return <div key={index}>{subItem.title}</div>;
                })}
              </div>


              <Link to={item.path}>
                {item.icon}
                <span>{item.title}</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
          );
        })}
```

This section of code is my attempt to display the array in the array, but I don't know how to properly display it without it crashing

```
       <div className='subnav-menu'>
                {SidebarData.subNav.map((subItem, index) => {
                  return <div key={index}>{subItem.title}</div>;
                })}
              </div>
```

How would I render the subNav array data?

Comment: in your code , subNav could be undefined, use `` SidebarData.subNav && SidebarData.subNav.map(....) `` or `` SidebarData.subNav?.map(...) `` instead

Answer (score 0):

First, You should call `subNav` of `item`, not `SidebarData`.
Also, you should check if subNav is undefined as you are calling `map()` method of the subNav, so if it's undefined, it occurs the error.

```
<div className='subnav-menu'>
                {item.subNav && item.subNav.map((subItem, index) => {
                  return <div key={index}>{subItem.title}</div>;
                })}
              </div>
```

Comment: ah so looks like this works. So in short it's saying if item.subNav is true, then display the array data?

Comment: correct, generally checking the array is always mandatory before calling the map function, because it could be error if it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <div className='subnav-menu'>
        {(SidebarData?.subNav || []).map((subItem, index) => {
          return <div key={index}>{subItem.title}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
```